# How to disable submit button when textbox, select and date are empty and enable when its done

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, forms

I've seen plenty examples of people disabling buttons if textboxes are empty but I haven't found any which will disable a button for only certain textboxes, date and select fields. I'm new to Jquery and I know it is pseudo coded but you can get the idea. Which Jquery function do I have to call so that it is constantly checking? And how can I use an or statement in the if clause to determine if any textbox field is empty?

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
    Username<br />
    <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" /><br />
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="password" /><br />
    Confirm Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    Birthday<br />
    <input type="date" id="bday" name="birthday" /><br /> 
    Sex<br />
    <select name="sex" id="sex">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript>
(function() {
    $('#myform > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input #bday').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LM4cf/)

Comment: Which one do you want to check for empty or not?

Comment: Have you looked at HTML5 form validation?  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: Check if available for the browser http://html5pattern.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `on('input')` and change your selector a bit:

```
$('#myform > input').on('input', function () {

    var empty = false;
    // Don't use an ID here
    $('form > input, form > select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x25pv/)

Answer (score 0):

You have your check on the birthday field, which is always filled because of the date input.

So make sure you check on other fields like this:

```
   $('form > input.cant_be_empty').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
   });
```

And add the cant_be_empty class to all elements which cannot be empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/LM4cf/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle. Basically, i've added a required attribute on the field you require. For example, if you require only the username add :

```
 <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" required="true" />
```

Then the js looks for the required fields and checks if they are empty :

```
(function() {
$('#myform > input').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > input[required="true"]').each(function(i, ele) {
        if ($(ele).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disable');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
}())
```

On the side, why not try this jQuery validation plugin [Here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation).
You can choose which fields are required as well as validate the user input before submitting the form (for example validate an email address).